# SyndicationFeed RSS Reader pubDate: error was encountered when parsing a datetime value

Tags: c#, rss, rss-reader, syndication

I'm developing simple C# application which will present rss feeds. I have problem reading rss feeds from some web pages. The problem comes when parsing pubDate: Error in line 1 position 829. An error was encountered when parsing a DateTime value in the XML.

```
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://vest.com.mk/rssGenerator/");
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

        foreach (var item in feed.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Title.Text);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(item.PublishDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do these things to get more information,

- Post the exception message to your problem description.
- Add a try catch around the code, and log the urls that fail.
- If there are any failing urls, try visit them looking for any 404s or anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code you pasted and the fact that your calling a bunch of feeds, my guess is that the PublishDate property might be null or returning a date format that can't be parsed.

Try checking for a null value on the DateFormat property.

Comment: I tried to remove `Console.WriteLine(item.PublishDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));` but I got the same error.

The error comes in this line `SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);`